# License for available for free, but closed source web app

Tags: licensing, free-software, closed-source

Anyone know of a free license that offers the user the right to use the software freely, but not modify it or share it?

In other words, it is closed source, but it's free. And since it's gonna be a website it can only be used on this one website.

What would be a good simply license for this? If possible that it's not too long, simple as the MIT license for example.

Comment: @Henry Oops, yes sorry, I will fix that.

Comment: I am sorry but your work is not free software.

Comment: @kush I don't understand what you mean... What I meant was that the web app is going to be freely available, but can only be used on it's own website, and it's going to be closed source. Similar to Twitter, Dictionary.com, FaceBook etc. They're free, but you can only use it on their website, and it's closed source.

Comment: Free software is an exact terminology with a specific meaning. Freeware is not necessarily free software. Please read more about what constitutes [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html) if you wish.

Comment: Ah I see... Thanks! I will read up on that, and find a license that's suitable. Thank you very much. :) Also, I fixed the title.

Answer (score 3):

I found several example [freeware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeware) licenses with [a simple search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=freeware+license).  Excerpting:

> You may
>
> - install and use any or all Product Elements included in the Product, as specified in the individual Terms of Use or License for each Product Element;
> - copy the Product, provided that such copies contain all the original Product's contents and proprietary notices. You may collect a reimbursement for the costs of producing the copy, but you may not charge a licensing fee for the Product;
> - place the Product or any Product Element on the Internet or any other public access network as long as you also acknowledge SIL and place a link back to the SIL product web page (if available);
> - permit other individuals to use the Product under the terms listed above.
>
> You may not
>
> - extract portions of a Product Element not permitted by the Terms of Use or Licenses for the Product Element;
> - sell licenses for the Product;
> - include the Product or any Product Element in any other collection or other product;
> - remove any proprietary notices on the Product or on any Product Element.

From [SIL](http://www.sil.org/computing/catalog/freeware.html).

> 1. Freeware
>
> You may use the SOFTWARE without charge. We may place announcement of other products into SOFTWARE. Intelligent-Digital.com will not monitor the content of your use (e.g., sites selected or files used).
>
> ...
>
> 1. RESTRICTIONS
>
> 3.1 You may not reverse engineer, de-compile, or disassemble the SOFTWARE.
>
> 3.2 You may not rent, lease, or lend the SOFTWARE.
>
> 3.3 You may permanently transfer all of your rights under this EULA, provided the recipient agrees to the terms of this EULA.
>
> 3.4 You may not use the SOFTWARE to perform any unauthorized transfer of information or for any illegal purpose.

From [Intelligent-digital.com](http://www.intelligent-digital.com/License-Freeware.htm).

> YOU MAY:
>   1. Install and use an unlimited number of copies for personal  use.
>
> YOU MAY NOT:
>   1. Sell Starz or any portion of it.
>   2. Decompile, disassemble, reverse engineer or modify the Starz executable or any portion of it.
>   3. Distribute Starz in any form.

From [ayretek](http://www.ayretek.com/downloads/freeware/Starz_License_Freeware.htm).

Comment: The license from Intelligent-digital.com seems to be the one nearest to what I want, however it's not exactly what I want. I will look the license, and if I can't find it I'll make mine or modify one of these. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no free software license that forbids modification or redistribution, since the software *would not be free / open source software*.

So, just do an “**All Rights Reserved**”, or get a lawer for further fine-tuning.

Comment: I see, I was planning on doing that. But providing a list of what they can and can't do in an elegant and professional matter seems like a better option. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.creativecommons.org is a nice simple way to build a license.  It has a short and simple version (i.e. layman version) and a lengthier legal version of each license.

You just pick things like "yes/no - people can modify my work", etc.

Comment: I tried using that, however the creative commons license isn't really what I'm looking for. Thanks though!